# switching views with NSMenuItem IBAction does not work

Tags: macos, nsview, nsmenu

In a document based Cocoa App I want to fill a NSBox in the Document.xib with a view,
by selecting the view with a NSMenuItem. However, the box is not updated with the view.
If I insert a button in the Document.xib, which is connected with the same IBAction as the NSMenuItem, the app works in the expected way.

[image: Document Window with cleared box]

[image: Document Window with selected view]

I created the tree files:
 - ViewController.h
 - ViewController.m
 - prettyView.xib

In ViewController.m the XIB File of the view is initialized.

```
//  ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController


- (id)init
{
    if(![super initWithNibName:@"prettyView" bundle:nil]){
        return nil;
    }
    [self setTitle:@"Pretty View"];
    return self;
}

@end
```

The Document.h contains outlets for the box and two buttons.
One button fills the box with the view, the other one clears the box.

```
//  Document.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class ViewController;

@interface Document : NSDocument
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSBox *contentBox;

- (IBAction)fillBox:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)clearBox:(id)sender;

@property   ViewController  * myViewController;

@end
```

In Document.m the view controller is instantiated.

```
//  Document.m
#import "Document.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface Document ()

@end

@implementation Document

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myViewController = [ViewController new];

    }
    return self;
}
```

The methods for the IBActions are implemented in Document.m too.

```
- (IBAction)fillBox:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Fill Box selected from %@", [sender className]);
    [self.contentBox setContentView:[self.myViewController view]];
}

- (IBAction)clearBox:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clear Box selected");
    [self.contentBox setContentView:nil];
}
```

The method **fillBox** is connected to one of the both buttons as well as to the NSMenuItem.
Pressing the button, a message is written to the console and the view is shown in the box.
Selecting the NSMenuItem, a message is written too, but the view is not displayed in the box.

Answer (score 1):

The IBActions must not be connected with Document but with First Responder of MainMenu.xib.